# Loop over an array of objects and filter/sort/group based on matching sets of a key value pair.

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting, ecmascript-6

I have some data like this:

```
"players": [
    {
    "name": "Molla Wague",
    "position": "Centre-Back",
    "jerseyNumber": 13,
    "dateOfBirth": "1991-02-21",
    "nationality": "Mali",
    "contractUntil": "2018-06-30",
    "marketValue": null
    },
    {
    "name": "Heurelho Gomes",
    "position": "Keeper",
    "jerseyNumber": 1,
    "dateOfBirth": "1981-02-15",
    "nationality": "Brazil",
    "contractUntil": "2019-06-30",
    "marketValue": null
    },
    {
    "name": "Christian Kabasele",
    "position": "Centre-Back",
    "jerseyNumber": 27,
    "dateOfBirth": "1991-02-24",
    "nationality": "Belgium",
    "contractUntil": "2021-06-30",
    "marketValue": null
    },
    {
    "name": "José Holebas",
    "position": "Left-Back",
    "jerseyNumber": 25,
    "dateOfBirth": "1984-06-27",
    "nationality": "Greece",
    "contractUntil": "2020-06-30",
    "marketValue": null
    },
    {
    "name": "Daryl Janmaat",
    "position": "Right-Back",
    "jerseyNumber": 2,
    "dateOfBirth": "1989-07-22",
    "nationality": "Netherlands",
    "contractUntil": "2020-06-30",
    "marketValue": null
    },
    {
    "name": "Étienne Capoue",
    "position": "Defensive Midfield",
    "jerseyNumber": 29,
    "dateOfBirth": "1988-07-11",
    "nationality": "France",
    "contractUntil": "2019-06-30",
    "marketValue": null
    },
    {
    "name": "Tom Cleverley",
    "position": "Central Midfield",
    "jerseyNumber": 8,
    "dateOfBirth": "1989-08-12",
    "nationality": "England",
    "contractUntil": "2022-06-30",
    "marketValue": null
    },
    {
    "name": "Roberto Pereyra",
    "position": "Attacking Midfield",
    "jerseyNumber": 37,
    "dateOfBirth": "1991-01-07",
    "nationality": "Argentina",
    "contractUntil": "2021-06-30",
    "marketValue": null
    },
    {
    "name": "Troy Deeney",
    "position": "Centre-Forward",
    "jerseyNumber": 9,
    "dateOfBirth": "1988-06-29",
    "nationality": "England",
    "contractUntil": "2021-06-30",
    "marketValue": null
    }
]
```

There are some players that have different **Positions**

I want to order each player by their position, So all Goalkeepers come first, then all Centre-Back's and so on.

I am using React and Redux. I have done some of the work in my Reducer file, but I think the code is too bloated, below is an example:

```
function sortPlayersByPosition(data) {
  let players = data.players;
  let result = [];

    result.push(players.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.position === 'Keeper';
    }));

    result.push(players.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.position === 'Centre-Back';
    }));

    result.push(players.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.position === 'Right-Back';
    }));

    result.push(players.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.position === 'Left-Back';
    }));

    result.push(players.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.position === 'Defensive Midfield';
    }));

    result.push(players.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.position === 'Central Midfield';
    }));

    result.push(players.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.position === 'Attacking Midfield';
    }));

    result.push(players.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.position === 'Right Wing';
    }));

    result.push(players.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.position === 'Left Wing';
    }));

    result.push(players.filter(function(obj) {
      return obj.position === 'Centre-Forward';
    }));

    data.players = result;

    return data
}

export const fetchTeamPlayersReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_TEAM_PLAYERS_SUCCESS':

        var sortedPlayers = sortPlayersByPosition(action.payload);
      return sortedPlayers;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

[Click here to see output of the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI6KI.png)

So as you can see I have got my positions separated into separate arrays. I do not desire this result. I would really like it if I had one array with the objects in order. Just like the original format.

Any help would be welcomed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can first make the array of ordered positions:

```
const ORDERS = [
  'Keeper',
  'Centre-Back',
  ...
]
```

And the sort your initial array by this ORDERS array

```
players.sort((player1, player2) => {
  return ORDERS.indexOf(player2.position) - ORDERS.indexOf(player1.position);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with:

```
const positions = [
  'Keeper', 'Centre-Back', 'Right-Back', 'Left-Back', 'Defensive Midfield',
  'Central Midfield', 'Attacking Midfield', 'Right Wing', 'Left Wing', 'Centre-Forward',
];

data.players.sort((a, b) => positions.indexOf(a.position) > positions.indexOf(b.position));
```

Output:

```
[{
  "name": "Heurelho Gomes",
  "position": "Keeper",
  "jerseyNumber": 1,
  "dateOfBirth": "1981-02-15",
  "nationality": "Brazil",
  "contractUntil": "2019-06-30",
  "marketValue": null,
}, {
  "name": "Molla Wague",
  "position": "Centre-Back",
  "jerseyNumber": 13,
  "dateOfBirth": "1991-02-21",
  "nationality": "Mali",
  "contractUntil": "2018-06-30",
  "marketValue": null,
}, {
  "name": "Christian Kabasele",
  "position": "Centre-Back",
  "jerseyNumber": 27,
  "dateOfBirth": "1991-02-24",
  "nationality": "Belgium",
  "contractUntil": "2021-06-30",
  "marketValue": null,
}, {
  "name": "Daryl Janmaat",
  "position": "Right-Back",
  "jerseyNumber": 2,
  "dateOfBirth": "1989-07-22",
  "nationality": "Netherlands",
  "contractUntil": "2020-06-30",
  "marketValue": null,
}, {
  "name": "José Holebas",
  "position": "Left-Back",
  "jerseyNumber": 25,
  "dateOfBirth": "1984-06-27",
  "nationality": "Greece",
  "contractUntil": "2020-06-30",
  "marketValue": null,
}, {
  "name": "Étienne Capoue",
  "position": "Defensive Midfield",
  "jerseyNumber": 29,
  "dateOfBirth": "1988-07-11",
  "nationality": "France",
  "contractUntil": "2019-06-30",
  "marketValue": null,
}, {
  "name": "Tom Cleverley",
  "position": "Central Midfield",
  "jerseyNumber": 8,
  "dateOfBirth": "1989-08-12",
  "nationality": "England",
  "contractUntil": "2022-06-30",
  "marketValue": null,
}, {
  "name": "Roberto Pereyra",
  "position": "Attacking Midfield",
  "jerseyNumber": 37,
  "dateOfBirth": "1991-01-07",
  "nationality": "Argentina",
  "contractUntil": "2021-06-30",
  "marketValue": null,
}, {
  "name": "Troy Deeney",
  "position": "Centre-Forward",
  "jerseyNumber": 9,
  "dateOfBirth": "1988-06-29",
  "nationality": "England",
  "contractUntil": "2021-06-30",
  "marketValue": null,
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an object containing sort priorities and define a custom sorting function as below:

```js
players = [
    {
    "name": "Molla Wague",
    "position": "Centre-Back",
    "jerseyNumber": 13,
    "dateOfBirth": "1991-02-21",
    "nationality": "Mali",
    "contractUntil": "2018-06-30",
    "marketValue": null
    },
    {
    "name": "Heurelho Gomes",
    "position": "Keeper",
    "jerseyNumber": 1,
    "dateOfBirth": "1981-02-15",
    "nationality": "Brazil",
    "contractUntil": "2019-06-30",
    "marketValue": null
    },
    {
    "name": "Christian Kabasele",
    "position": "Centre-Back",
    "jerseyNumber": 27,
    "dateOfBirth": "1991-02-24",
    "nationality": "Belgium",
    "contractUntil": "2021-06-30",
    "marketValue": null
    },
    {
    "name": "José Holebas",
    "position": "Left-Back",
    "jerseyNumber": 25,
    "dateOfBirth": "1984-06-27",
    "nationality": "Greece",
    "contractUntil": "2020-06-30",
    "marketValue": null
    },
    {
    "name": "Daryl Janmaat",
    "position": "Right-Back",
    "jerseyNumber": 2,
    "dateOfBirth": "1989-07-22",
    "nationality": "Netherlands",
    "contractUntil": "2020-06-30",
    "marketValue": null
    },
    {
    "name": "Étienne Capoue",
    "position": "Defensive Midfield",
    "jerseyNumber": 29,
    "dateOfBirth": "1988-07-11",
    "nationality": "France",
    "contractUntil": "2019-06-30",
    "marketValue": null
    },
    {
    "name": "Tom Cleverley",
    "position": "Central Midfield",
    "jerseyNumber": 8,
    "dateOfBirth": "1989-08-12",
    "nationality": "England",
    "contractUntil": "2022-06-30",
    "marketValue": null
    },
    {
    "name": "Roberto Pereyra",
    "position": "Attacking Midfield",
    "jerseyNumber": 37,
    "dateOfBirth": "1991-01-07",
    "nationality": "Argentina",
    "contractUntil": "2021-06-30",
    "marketValue": null
    },
    {
    "name": "Troy Deeney",
    "position": "Centre-Forward",
    "jerseyNumber": 9,
    "dateOfBirth": "1988-06-29",
    "nationality": "England",
    "contractUntil": "2021-06-30",
    "marketValue": null
    }
];

sortOrder = {
 "Keeper": 0,
 "Centre-Back": 1,
 "Centre-Forward": 2,
 "Left-Back": 3,
 "Right-Back": 4,
 "Defensive Midfield": 5,
 "Central Midfield": 6,
 "Attacking Midfield": 7,

};

function sort(player1, player2) {
 const player1Value = sortOrder[player1.position];
 const player2Value = sortOrder[player2.position];
 if(player1Value > player2Value) { return 1; }
 else if (player1Value < player2Value) { return -1; }
 else { return 0; }
}

console.log(players.sort(sort));
```